# Как адаптировать виджет комментариев?

Tags: вконтакте, комментарии, виджет

Я адаптировал виджет по ширине блока, в котором он находится; но дело в том, что при публикации в нем картинки большого размера (имеется в виду, что виджет шириной к примеру 500px, а картинка 800px) картинка обрезается. Для того чтобы она встала полностью на весь размер в чате нужно обновлять страницу.
Так выглядит картинка после публикации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так картинка выглядит после обновления страницы сайта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Никак, даже если выставить width: 'auto', то сработает расчет размеров только при загрузке виджета. Можно конечно переписать стили индивидуально для кнопок, записей и картинок, но смысл?

Comment: А еще такой вопрос. Я добавил виджет комментариев, мой сайт поддерживает мобильную версия, но проблема в том что  
в обычной версии комментарии ВК выглядят нормально, а при мобильной версии ширина виджета ВК остается такой же как и была изначально в 698px.

Comment: прописал в стилях - #vk_comments, #vk_comments iframe {
  width: 100% !important;
 }

Comment: но это не помогло, ширина с мобильного все равно не изменилаяь

Comment: [Параметр `width`](https://vk.com/dev/widget_comments) у виджета просто не указывайте и он будет адаптивным. Никакой CSS не нужен.

Comment: Вот, даже лучше вариант предложили)
Пока не сталкивался с постоянным изменением элементов виджета.